# Editing a file generated with print with gnuplot

Tags: windows, gnuplot

I have generated two column data files (`$Data1` and `&Data2`) with `set table`; here are the first values of `Data1`:

```
01/11/2021 00:15:00   15.0  70.0    0.10    1010.0  0.8 228 1.4 0.0    
01/11/2021 00:30:00   14.8  71.0    0.20    1010.0  1.0 200 1.9 0.0  
01/11/2021 00:45:00   14.6  73.0    0.30    1010.1  0.8 142 1.4 0.0  
01/11/2021 01:00:00   14.6  74.0    0.20    1010.0  1.2 147 2.0 0.0
```

and `Data2`:

```
01/11/2021 00:15:00   14.8  56.0    0.00    1012.0  2.1 228 4.8 0.0  
01/11/2021 00:30:00   14.2  59.0    0.00    1012.1  2.7 202 5.8 0.0  
01/11/2021 00:45:00   14.6  62.0    0.00    1012.0  1.6 228 3.4 0.0  
01/11/2021 01:00:00   14.0  65.0    0.00    1011.9  1.9 228 3.3 0.0
```

I have merged them into a new file called `$Data` with `print`, like this:

```
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:|$Data1|-6] { print $Data1[i] }
    do for [i=1:|$Data2|-6] { print $Data2[i] }
set print
```

I know how to plot the file `$Data`, but do you know how to edit it? (by editing I mean to be able to read the numerical values, not to plot them)

Comment: What do you mean with editing? Changing some specific numbers? Please give a minimal example of `$Data1` and `$Data2` and what exactly you want to change.

Comment: what do you mean with "reading" values? What do you want to do with the values? For example, do you want to put the value of the 3rd line and 6th column into a variable? Please clarify.

Comment: An additional remark: Calling `$Data` a file might lead to misunderstanding, because it is not stored on a disk, but only in RAM. If you just want to see its content, `print $Data` should suffice? Otherwise, as theozh said, we'd need more clarification.